# Want recommendations for new Laser Color Printer for Ubuntu 18.04+

Tags: usb, networking, printer, scanner, laser

My current printer is an HP Color LaserJet 2550L. It has worked great for a long time, but now it decided to [not print at all anymore](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1214166/all-of-a-sudden-my-hp-laserjet-2550l-decided-to-stop-printing-any-idea-what-c). I'm not too sure why that would be but I have been having more and more problems with it and it can't print large images (probably because it's limited to 64 MB of RAM, which in 2004 seemed like quite a bit already).

So I'm looking for a new multi-function printer and want recommendations. Here are the specifications I'm interested in:

- Works great on Ubuntu 18.04+
- Color Laser (no inkjet, please)
- Multifunction - Printer, Fax, Scan, Copy
- Duplex Scan and Copy
- Two Sided Printing
- Automatic Scan
- Separate Color Toners
- Standard Paper Size (US Letter/A4)
- Internal Paper Feeder (at least 100 pages)
- Output bin should support at least 20 pages
- Connect by Ethernet and/or USB (no WiFi/Bluetooth)
- Budget around $500

What I mean by "automatic scan" is a way to be able to scan an entire stack at once (for example, place all the pages of a contract in the machine and push one button).

The Copy feature should work on its own (no computer involved); like any photocopier.

Fax is really not that important.

Comment: B2 or A4? A4 is standard, B2 is huge (50x70 cm) and probably wouldn't make it in your budget with all those features, if they even make them.

Comment: Also, are you ok with WiFi being available but disabled if there is Ethernet or USB too? Or do you want it explicitly not present?

Comment: @JanDorniak Sorry, I meant US Letter. I guess there isn't a simple letter/number for that one.

Comment: no, I don't think so. I actually wanted to check what printer we have in office for you but forgot.

Comment: Note that HP printers stop working if automatic ink purchase is stopped: https://www.howtogeek.com/403346/hps-ink-subscription-has-drm-that-disables-your-printer-cartridges/ . That might explain your issue.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Interesting (and really bad). I never subscribed and the printer worked for more than 10 years...

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend Brother MFC color lasers, such as the [MFCL3770CDW](https://www.brother-usa.com/products/mfcl3770cdw) which, at $400 retail, satisfies all of your specifications. Ubuntu drivers are available for direct [download as a DEB file](https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadtop.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=mfcl3770cdw_us_eu_as).

Comment: Are the Brother's drivers as good as the HP drivers? I've read that HP was better in that area, but maybe the other manufacturers have caught up by now?

Comment: I am happy with my B&W Brother, but do not have a color Brother.